# Setting Alarm for different timezones using AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, calendar, timezone, alarmmanager

My `Android` application needs to set a number of alarms over the next few weeks using the `AlarmManager`.  As of now, I'm planning to hard code those date/times using an array of calendar objects.

The question I'm facing is, how do I handle different timezones? Supposing I set an alarm for 
`2nd August 2012 15:00 GMT` , how do I make sure that a person using the app somewhere else (say India i.e. GMT+5.30) gets the alarm at `2nd August 2012 20:30`

Is there a way the app can get the timezone difference (i.e. the '+5.30' part) of that particular device so that before setting the alarm, to each `Calendar` object I can add that difference and then set the alarm?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `System.currentTimeMillis()`, Which should return u the time of system depends on what timezone the phone is in

Comment: And then do what with it??? 
Unless I can also get the current time at GMT and then get the difference between that and the system time, and then add that to the alarm time.